# Should the description of the site be changed?

Tags: discussion, scope

When I look at [the description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) of Language Learning, I see:

> Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of **second-language acquisition** (emphasis is my own)

Should this be generalized? I don't think this site is specifically for *second-language* acquisiton; rather, I believe it is for language acquisition.

That is to say, I believe a more accurate/reflective description might be:

> Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of language acquisition

Answer (score 4):

Second-language acquisition is defined as the process by which people learn a second language. In turn, a [second language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_language) is defined as

> any language learned in addition to one's native language, especially in context of second language acquisition, (that is, learning a new foreign language).

As such, second-language acquisition refers to the acquisition of any languages other than your first.

However, I agree with you. The common passerby won't take the time to define the terms "SLA" and "second language", and as such, I think your proposed description is more simplistic for one to understand. (Although the original is still technically correct.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree.

Second language acquisition by itself makes no sense as you can trying to be bilingual or multilingual, just using the help from this site. The description should be changed to a much broader range:

> Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of language acquisition

or for originality-ish:

> Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques and practices of acquiring new languages

or just

> Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in learning other languages

Comment: As long as you include "techniques and practices", I don't see why you can't just use *learning*: "... anyone interested in the techniques and practices of *learning* new languages." While "acquisition" and "acquire" have meaning here, they often refer to things, and I don't think these words are the best choices in context.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, that your suggested wording is more accurate.  However, the wording on Area51 isn't especially important at this point. And, as far as I know (someone correct me if I'm wrong), that phrase doesn't exist anywhere else.

Eventually (soon, I expect), we'll have some Pro Tem moderators, and we'll begin fleshing out our per-site FAQ pages, on-topic criteria, etc.  When we do so, this is a perfect opportunity to clarify and/or change our site's description as it appears in these places. And I definitely think your suggestion should be taken into consideration during this phase.

Comment: I discovered it when pasting the link to the language learning site - it appears in the site description. See [slack image here](http://imgur.com/0BNyyF1).