# Can we widen the scope of this site to include questions about language policies that are relevant to learning or teaching languages?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked a [question about the European Day of Languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/evidence-that-the-european-day-of-languages-motivates-eu-citizens-to-learn-forei) because one of its goals is to motivate people to learn foreign languages.

Language policy that is relevant to language learning or language teaching was probably not considered as a topic for this site. However, I would like to make a plea for adding this topic to the site's scope, because I think that the initial idea (just techniques for SLA) should not work as a straightjacket that prevents the site from growing.

If accepted, the site's description (e.g. at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)) would need to be adapted. (In fact, there is also an [older question](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/should-the-description-of-the-site-be-changed) that requested a change that has not been implemented yet.)

Comment: I think the question is on-topic: as far as I can tell, the question definitely *does* relate to second-language acquisition. Also, if it *was* off-topic, where could it be migrated to? LL.SE seems to be the best fit of the sites we have now.

Comment: I agree with Hatchet. I think your question is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Hatchet - Is migratability a factor in determining inclusion here? This seems to be a point of difference between SEs and between individual mods: The question's-eye-view asks "Where can this high quality question find a good home?" while the site's-eye-view asks "Can I handle this high quality question?".

Comment: @WAF the reason I included the comment about migrating is because sites' scopes have been modified with the addition of new sites, for example SO & SU, or SO & SF, or Unix & AU, or SU & any of the smaller software-specific sites like Blender. There are no other sites where this question would be more on-topic than here.